# Set button size with pixels

Tags: java, android

In my application I control the size of my button proportionally with the screen size:

```
    int screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    int screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int buttonWidth = (int) (screenWidth * 0.07);
    int buttonHeight = (int) (buttonWidth * 1.2);
```

The button takes the same space (for example 5 %) of the device's screen size. What I want now is that the button's text takes the same space of the button area on every device.

I tried this:

```
   int textSize = (int) (buttonHeight * 0.145);
   myButton.setTextSize((float) (textSize));
```

I don't know why but on bigger screens (such as tablets) the text uses a lot less space of the button than on smaller screens. 
Thanks !
Maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying the unit of measurement like this:

```
myButton.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, (float) (textSize));
```

`setTextSize` uses `sp` units by default instead of px, so that might be causing your issue!